# Brew - How to stop losing app settings when updating?

Tags: macos, mac, applications, homebrew

I am using Brew for almost every app in my Mac, and I'm always trying to keep all these apps updated, so I set up the `brew autoupdate` command to run daily. The problem is I did realize that every time it updates my apps, it keeps replacing the app for a new one, and because of that the Mac keeps losing informations about this apps, suck like Notifications settings. It also always requires permission to open the apps since "This app was downloaded from the internet" every once. How can I avoid these problems and keep all the apps up to date?

Comment: Doesn't an update imply that the binary gets replaced?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't mean that the system should lose the reference of the settings, so the way Brew is doing it might be wrong. Maybe a Brew setting that's not correct.

Comment: This might be caused by Homebrew using a new directory for each version.

Comment: @nohillside Indeed, it is. I searched for it and the folder where Brew is keeping the apps is considering it's version (e.g. /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/slack/4.34.121)
Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: You can avoid this by not using casks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you're using cask for some reason.  `Brew` cask downloads from the developer's web site and replaces the binary with that download.  So yes, macOS is going to detect that the app was changed.  This is not a `brew` problem (other than the fundamental problem that cask is).

Comment: You are right, I am using cask, i just copied the commands in the formulae (e.g. brew install -cask slack) and used it to install the apps. Is there a way to remove the cask option of the app so it will not be considered as a cask anymore when updating?

Comment: It's not an "option of the app".  Homebrew pretends they are packaging the app, when in reality they're just going out and downloading the developer's packages.  So just download the software from the developer yourself.

Comment: I see. Well, I think that's the way. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to some of the comments, Homebrew stores the installed version of a cask in `/Applications`. `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom` is only for storing backups of installer packages, old versions of apps, etc.

The issue with the "This app was downloaded from the internet" prompt is a macOS feature, and would also happen if you simply downloaded the latest version manually and installed it. Homebrew will only update casks that don't have built-in updaters (unless you pass `--greedy`), so this should only happen with apps that you'd have to manually update (and encounter the same dialog when doing so) anyway. (There *is* an option in Homebrew to disable the quarantine flag that causes this, but doing so bypasses the macOS Gatekeeper checks, reducing security, so is not recommended.)

As for losing the likes of notification settings, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/102721) that was supposedly resolved. However, if this is happening with apps like Slack which are supposed to update themselves, then you've probably configured the `--greedy` option somewhere. This causes Homebrew to update **all** casks, even those that update themselves. I'd recommend disabling this, so Homebrew only updates casks that don't have inbuilt updaters.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I am interested if it is possible to turn off such `those that update themselves` option? I hate to see pop ups here and there that my applications are getting obsolete. I want to update them once a week and don't want to know if there update available.

Comment: @GHopper Most applications have a 'Check for updates' option that you can turn off.

Comment: let's take a few most popular for me: GoogleChrome, Telegram, Docker, PHPStorm. Is it possible to turn off "check for updates" at least for some of them?